# Tversky and Kahneman's belief in the law of small numbers correlations

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

In Tversky and Kahneman (1971), they ask:

> You have run a correlational study, scoring 20 variables on 100 subjects. Twenty-seven of the 190 correlation coefficients are significant at the .05 level; and 9 of these are significant beyond the .01 level. The mean absolute level of the significant correlations is .31, and the pattern of results is very reasonable on theoretical grounds. How many of the 27 significant correlations would you expect to be significant again, in an exact replication of the study, with N = 40?

They make the point that with half the sample, you would expect only half of the same correlations to be significant (i.e., only 13 or 14 of the original 27) and that via regression some of the larger effects would revert. Then they state:

> Hence, by regression effects, the initially significant coefficients are most likely to be reduced. Thus, 8 to 10 repeated significant correlations from the original 27 is probably a generous estimate of what one is entitled to expect. The median estimate of our respondents is 18. This is more than the number of repeated significant correlations that will be found if the correlations are recomputed for 40 subjects randomly selected from the original 100

How do they conclude that only 8 - 10 of those remaining correlations should be significant at half of the sample size?

Tversky, A., & Kahneman, D. (1971). Belief in the law of small numbers. Psychological bulletin, 76(2), 105.